# Display signal cuts out due to static electricity

Tags: hardware-failure, thinkpad, displayport, mini-displayport, static-discharge

I have two monitors hooked up to a Thinkpad T450 using Displayport MST, and every once in a while, the signal would cut out briefly before coming back. I had no idea what the issue was, and I suspected a driver issue, but then I noticed a pattern. It happens whenever there is a static discharge nearby. Not even touching the laptop or monitors, just like, any discharge within a 10 foot radius. Someone taking off a jacket or standing up out of a chair. Since this discovery, everyone in the office has been having fun at my expense!

I have no idea where to even begin with solving this problem. I'm thinking it could be that the Displayport cable is low-quality, or because the laptop power brick is ungrounded, or that maybe because it's sitting up on an ungrounded metal stand. Any ideas?

Comment: Ground everything.

Comment: Can you try a different monitor?

Comment: For sure it's a question of grounding

Answer (score -1):

I've had this issue many times with DP-cables. From what I've learned, apparently what happens is that static electricity builds up over time in the cable itself and eventually causes the screen to blackout. This is especially a problem in working environments with lots of static electricity (obviously), eg. offices with carpet tiles. 
Disconnect the cable and let it discharge for a couple of days and it works again. The solution is to have a spare cable laying around to replace the one causing the issue atm.